# Fonts for Unicode CJK extensions C, D, E

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know of a font that supports the unicode CJK extensions c, d, e? If you have such a font, do you know if it works with the MySQL utf8mb4 character set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Hanazono](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/) fonts (HanaMinA, HanaMinB) have full support for all 3 extensions and include 96k+ glyphs. Here is the [glyph list](http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.jp/hanazono-font/62073/glyphlist.pdf) (.pdf, 500 pages).

[Babelstone Han](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html) claims to support all glyphs in Extension D, but only has partial support for C (37.1%) and E (19.5%).

EDIT:

Here's the [download link](http://iij.dl.sourceforge.jp/hanazono-font/62072/hanazono-20141012.zip) (25.7MB) for *HanaMinB* (which supports these extensions). And here's a screenshot of a word processor with HanaMinB.ttf installed, displaying random glyphs from CJK Ext. E.

[image]

Comment: Hanazono really supports CJK-E?

Comment: @user3306356 See the screenshot in my updated answer.

Comment: Great font, but I'm still having trouble with Ext. E.  After installing HanaMin A & B in Windows 7, I can now see the Ext. C and Ext. D glyphs in Wikipedia (using Firefox 39).  However, I'm still unable to see any of the Ext. E glyphs on Wiki. In addition, when I go to the Unihan database, I can only see glyphs up to 2A6DF (i.e. Ext. B); C, D, and E don't show at all. I'll keep fiddling with it; any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried restarting your browser? I assume, yes. Open this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E , right click on any of the glyphs in the table and select "Inspect Element" from the context menu. Check the font on the 'Fonts' tab.

Comment: Yes, shutdown and restarted computer to be sure. Inspect element shows HanaMinB font for glyphs in ext. c and d tables in wiki, but 'arial' for ext. e. How come? Also, tried to copy text to Word (2003), b ext is fine, but c, d, and e are no good.  Same for copying to mysql tables (server 5.5.39)

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the error, I am running Linux and things are fine.

Comment: Hm. Tried Chrome and IE 11 and the same story.  Wonder if I have some sort of font conflict? I tried changing the default font for x-unicode in Firefox to HanaMin B; no soap.  Anyone else got suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried Default font: serif? The wikipedia page with the CJK-E table is using font-family: sans-serif, on Windows your fallback font is probably a sans-serif one, like Arial. I have no idea if that should fall back to anything else on Windows, but it does resort to HanaMinB system in my browser. I haven't modified any font settings in Firefox.

Comment: It seems to be an individual problem for my system. Anyway, I'm sure this is the solution for most people

Comment: Mac OS X, Safari & Chrome: all are fine.

Comment: CJK Unified Ideographs Extension E is part of Unicode 8.0, it is not implemented in OS X, neither 10.10 Yosemite nor 10.11 El Capitan. Therefore, it does not show up, since it is not recognized by the system.

However, a few characters in Extension E do show up, using Noto Sans CJK fonts. A contradiction in terms, but it may have to do with how these fonts are coded.

Comment: @倪阔乐 I'm using Yosemite, why can I see all the characters on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_E)? (I've installed HanaMin before.)

Comment: @Stan: I don't know, I am guessing it is not HanaMin but another font. Open TextEdit, Go to Edit/Emoji & Symbols, choose Unicode and scroll down the list. You will see that extensions B, C and D exist, followed by Compatibility Ideographs Supp. Extension E is not defined. Copy the first character of the wiki page and see if you can render it using HanaMin in TextEdit. I strongly believe it is another font rendered.

Comment: @倪阔乐 I tried, and the result showed in TextEdit HanaMinB could correctly display ext E characters. (Maybe you want to verify this by yourself?) Yes ext E isn't defined in "Emoji & Symbols", but it doesn't mean Unicode within that area cannot be tackled by the system -- that may be why we can see "squares" if no font provides a glyph on the specific Unicode code points.

Comment: @wpt I had the same problem, it turned out I had an old version on HanaMinA and HanaMinB installed on my computer! it was from '13 or something like that - the newest version is from '14 - I downloaded the newest version and everything was hunky doory

Comment: Yop, that's right, works just fine with the newest version, must have gotten the old version at scourgeforge.